# Square root of differential operator

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $D_x$ is the differential operator. eg. $D_x x^3=3 x^2$.

How can I find out what the operator $Q_x=(1+(k D_x)^2)^{(-1/2)}$ does to a (differentiable) function $f(x)$? ($k$ is a real number)

For instance what is $Q_x x^3$?

Comment: Whenever in want for $f(D)$ performed on a specific function, where $D$ is an operator, I think it's generally a good idea to expand $f$ as a power series in $D$. For instance, $$Qx^3=x^3-3k^2x$$ (with aid from [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+for+1%2F%281%2Ba+x^2%29^%281%2F2%29)).

Comment: Fractional powers of differential operators have been studied since the beginnings of calculus. One possible interpretation of your operator $Q_x$ could be rooted using fractional calculus: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_derivative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$1+kD^2$ has positive spectrum but this is not enough for the existence of a square root operator on the same space of functions.  This is because derivative is an unbounded operator (so that the expansion of $Q_x$ as a power series in $D$ may not converge), and the square root function is multi-valued.

The restriction to functions that are polynomials does give a well-defined $Q$ using the power series.

Answer (score 8):

It probably means this: Expand the expression $(1+(kt)^2)^{-1/2}$ as a power series in $t$, getting
$$
a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + a_3 t^3 + \cdots,
$$
and then put $D_x$ where $t$ was:
$$
a_0 + a_1 D_x + a_2 D_x^2 + a_3 D_x^3 + \cdots
$$
and then apply that operator to $x^3$:
$$
a_0 x^3 + a_1 D_x x^3 + a_2 D_x^2 x^3 + a_3 D_x^3 x^3 + \cdots.
$$
All of the terms beyond the ones shown here will vanish, so you won't have an infinite series.

Answer (score 4):

Dirac won a Nobel Prize for finding the square root of a pesky differential operator while working on the relativistic Schrodinger equation. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zM-Lc16nyho. <--- That video  gives a clear overview of the hacks Dirac used.