# the square root of a differential operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

For $x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ I want to know the definitions of the following operator

$\sqrt{D_x^2+x^2}$

$|D_x|$

Thanks

Comment: Related?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67904/square-root-of-differential-operator?rq=1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Dirac's_coup